# Visual Studio 2015 Black Screen on Exception

Tags: c#, .net, exception, visual-studio-2015, targetinvocationexception

I have visual studio 2015.
Almost every exception thrown by external APIs cause the following black screen with the title "Source Not Available" with the TargetInvocationException without any further information.

[image]

Does anybody know how can I get some details about the original exception?

Comment: googling the second line in that picture will lead you to a lot more helpful information than I think someone would be able to offer here. When I did it, the first link that came up showed how to determine what files were missing and what to do to resolve it.

Answer (score 0):

The exception dialog should have a `View details` link (I'm not sure why it doesn't on your screenshot): `TargetInvocationException` usually has the `InnerException` property set to the actual thrown exception.

If it doesn't show on the first "black screen" as you call it, try debugging (F5) again, you *should* see the full exception dialog